# next string of a stream in VB.net

Tags: python, vb.net, stream

I have a some bunch of python files. I need to get all the classes from there and make a list. 
its like I have to read with streamreader and then

**Imports ActionBlock**

I have to take the string ActionBlock and show it in a list. Listing and others hopefully I can do, but I am stuck in this point. Any suggestion please? Thank you.

Comment: Post the code you have so far along with a sample of the python file so we can see what the issue is

Comment: Are you trying to read all class definitions or all imports? Your question is not very clear...

Comment: Actually some classes are imported in python files. And yeah I have to make a list of those.  So with reading the stream I can detect "import". but i cant do the rest. thank you

Comment: import DataArchiving
import TABasicFunctions
import HWDataConveterGate
import GeneralTestDataMapping

Comment: @DominicKexel can you please explain me a little how did you wrote the  syntex. I tried this for .c file. i tried include instead of import. but as expected it was bullshit idea. want to get tips to be an informatiker from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to look for the parts you're interested in.

The following code

```
Dim path = "c:\path\to\your\file.py"
Dim content = File.ReadAllText(path)

Dim matchClass = "class (?<m>\w+)(:|\()+"
Dim matchImport = "(^|from \w+ )import ((?<m>\w+), )*(?<m>\w+)"

Dim result = Regex.Matches(content, String.Format("({0}|{1})", matchClass, matchImport), RegexOptions.Multiline) _
                  .Cast(Of Match) _
                  .SelectMany(Function(m) m.Groups("m").Captures.Cast(Of Capture).Select(Function(c) c.Value)) _
                  .ToList()
```

will, given a text file like

```
import os 
import math 
from time import clock 
from random import randint 
import DataArchiving 
import TABasicFunctions 
import HWDataConveterGate 
import GeneralTestDataMapping
from something import FirstClass, SecondClass

def foo():
    pass

def bar():
    pass

class ClassOne(object):
    class NestedClass:
        pass

    def thisisnotaclass(self):
        v = [x.class for x in self]
        v = [x.someimport for x in self]

class ClassTwo:
    pass

class Class3:
    pass

def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

create a list that looks like:

[image]

Comment: you are too cool...do you stay in Germany?? @Dominic Kexel...aber es war supercool..

Comment: its nice meeting you. it seems you have great expertise. I live in Friedrichshafen. Currently bachelor student and for doing workstudent I needed this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I got another problem. I have to paste some string before import. Like for python I need to add the directories(directory list is given). I know how to read from excel file. So I just need that, if I want to paste a string before import, how to do this in the script? Please

Comment: It's hard to answer questions in comments. Better ask a new question.